# Laravel: why Eloquent Models methods should be invoked as fields

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new at Laravel, I have stumbled up on a very interesting concept in Laravel Eloquent Models. When I create a model lets say Tweet.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tweet extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then when I want to call the user method normally `Tweet::first()->user()` it dose not return the required result instead it returns (which I assume it is a closure or a reference):

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
```

While it works perfectly when I treated it as a filed and invoked it without the parenthesis `Tweet::first()->user` then I will get the actual data which is the uses's information.

Would you please let me know what is this concept, how it works, and how can we replicate it with our code.

Comment: first thing would be looking into how magic methods work in PHP  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php specifically `__get`

Comment: @lagbox I have though about magic functions but could not find a relation between them as they are reserved ones as I think

Comment: have you looked at the `Model` class?  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1784 ... if you follow that path you will get to where it checks for a relationship, loads it and returns it ... though you will have to to navigate through some traits

Comment: @lagbox Yes I did but it is really very large and I did not find any reference to this behaviour. and I do not think I can find any theoretical background of the basis of this phenomena. as It might be exist in php language itself

Comment: that is the reference to it

Comment: @lagbox Thank you very much. I appreciate your time and patience with me.

Comment: if you follow that `__get` -> `getAttribute` you will eventually get to https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6e563129f679ea0a6fbcb2747e3be77bab3bff1c/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L427 ... and the difference between `->relationship` and `->realtionship()` is this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties ... it might seem like there is a lot of magic happening but its not that crazy, its just these methods are broken up over different traits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @lagbox the difference is described in the manual under [Relationship methods vs. dynamic properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

For more detail:
`Tweet::first()->user()` will return a **query** which can be used to retrieve the user (or be further refined) e.g. you can do `Tweet::first()->user()->where('name', 'Bob')->first()` to  retrieve the user associated with the first tweet if the user's name is Bob. This makes no sense in this context but makes sense in the reverse direction where you can e.g. do `User::first()->tweets()->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())` to get all of today's tweets.

When you do `Tweet::first()->user` this tries to get the relationship `user` if it's loaded or lazy loads it if it's not loaded. For more information on how to optimise this loading you can check [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in the manual